# How to format the Displaytag total value in Indian format?

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

I have implemented custom decorator and formatted the numbers in Indian format style. But how do i do this for total. Below is the code which i used. Give me an idea to format total value.

```
<display:column property="amount" sortable="false" total="true"
                    titleKey="table.title.amount"
                    decorator="com.vms.adhiparasakthi.web.decorator.ExpenseColumnDecorator"
                    style="width:100px;text-align:right;" />
<display:footer>
                    <tr class="total">
                        <td colspan="9" class="tdborder"><s:text name="label.total"></s:text>
                        </td>
                        <td><fmt:setLocale value="en_IN" scope="request" /><fmt:formatNumber
                            type="number" pattern="#,##0.00" groupingUsed="true">
                            <s:property value="%{#attr.total.column10}" />
                        </fmt:formatNumber></td>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <tr>
                </display:footer>
```

Comment: You mean to say the new **Indian Rupee Symbol** ?

Comment: No, formatting style. like ##,##,##0.00

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override 'total' css class into your jsp and in that class apply whatever formatting style you want.Only the thing is that class must be after all imports so it will take your changes.